# Error header("location:...")

Tags: php, web, hosting, headers

Estoy en construcción de un sitio y será el primero que lo pondré en la web de manera profesional. Para hacer pruebas lo alojé en un host gratuito *"000webhost.com"*. Debo aclarar que en mi servidor local *XAMPP* funcionaba sin problema alguno, y aquí me esta dando un dolor de cabeza. Ya llevo casi 6 horas buscando una solución.

Mi sitio web es `https://visordetrabajo.000webhostapp.com/`. Cuestión: que como dice el titulo, cuando utilizo el *"header"* no me direcciona a la pagina que deseo. Aclaro que he leído en varios topics sobre este tema y he usado varias de sus soluciones pero ninguna me sirvió.

He probado:

- borrar el cache del navegador
- he agregado al archivo *.htaccess* la siguiente `"php_value output_buffering on"`
- he agregado al inicio de la etiqueta php `ob_start ();` y luego del  header `ob_end_flush ();`
- he agregado al final del header `exit()`
- he comprobado si la dirección sería `header("Location: /public_html/visor.php")` ya que en dicho host se coloca los archivos en la carpeta `public_html`   o bien `("Location: visor.php")` como lo tenia codificado de un principio.

En definitiva, he probado todo lo que encontré en el foro y lamentablemente no funciona nada. Paso a agregar el código del login, de la pagina a donde quiero direccionar y del *.htaccess*. Cabe aclarar que he visto también cambiar el header por código *JavaScript*, pero me parece un poco tedioso cambiar todo el código por algo que en mi servidor local *XAMPP* funciona pero no en el servidor 000webhost...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Usuario:</label><input type="text" name="usuario"> 
<br/>
<label>Password:</label><input type="password" 
name="password"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"><br/>
</form>
<?php
ob_start ();
include("conexion.php");
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
if(!empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
   //Selecting database
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE dni='".$usuario ."' AND password='".$password."'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
    if($numrows !=0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
        {
            $nombreusu=$row['nombres'];
            $apellidousu=$row['apellidos'];
            $dbusuario=$row['dni'];
            $dbpassword=$row['password'];
        }
        if($usuario == $dbusuario && $password == $dbpassword)
        {
         session_start();
            $_SESSION["sess_usuario"]=$usuario;
            $_SESSION["sess_nombre"]=$nombreusu;
            $_SESSION["sess_apellido"]=$apellidousu;
           header("Location: visor.php");
           ob_end_flush ();
          exit ();
        }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script>alert('¡Usuario o contaseña 
incorrecta!');window.location= 'login.php'</script>";
    }
}
else
{
echo "Required All fields!";
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Aquí el código de visor.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_usuario'])){
header("Location: index.php");
exit ();
}
else
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Visor de Trabajos</title>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="estilos.css" TYPE="text/css">
 <script  src="fecha.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 //* configuracion database.
include("conexion.php");
$consulta = "SELECT seguimientos.*, usuarios.nombres, usuarios.apellidos FROM seguimientos, usuarios WHERE seguimientos.usuario_recepcion=(SELECT ID_usuarios FROM usuarios WHERE dni=".$_SESSION['sess_usuario'].") AND usuarios.ID_usuarios=seguimientos.usuario_envio";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
?>
<div id="arriba">
<img src="logo.png" alt="IPEC Misiones" >
  <p id="fecha"><script>fecha("fecha")</script></p>
  <h1>VISOR DE TRABAJOS</h1>
  <h3>
        <?php echo "".$_SESSION['sess_nombre']." ".$_SESSION['sess_apellido']."";?> 
        <a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a> 
  </h3> 

 </div>
 <div id="centro">
 <h3>TRABAJOS PENDIENTES</h3>
  <?php
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
    {
  ?>
      <ul>
        <li type='square' id=>
          <?php 
              echo "<span id='lista'>Trabajo N°<a id='pendientes' href='http://www.google.com'>".$fila[4]."</a>  enviado por <b>$fila[10] $fila[11]</b> el día $fila[7] a las $fila[8] horas </span>";
          ?>
          <div id='observaciones'>
            <?php echo $fila[9] ?>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul> 
  <?php
    }
  ?>
 </div>

 <div id="derecha"></div>
 <div id="abajo"></div>

 </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Código del archivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
php_value output_buffering on
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

Muchas gracias por leer y por futuras respuestas.

Comment: Debes realizar la validación antes del Tag <html> así como lo tienes en visor.php. No puedes modificar los headers cuando estos ya han sido enviados.

Comment: No puedes usar `header` de ningún tipo si previamente has sacado algo por pantalla, con `echo, print, var_dump ...` etc, o abriendo bloques HTML como de hecho haces. [Lee la documentación en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php), para que comprendas cómo funcionan las redirecciones. Eso está explicado de forma diáfana en el Manual.

Comment: pido disculpas por ello, sucede que soy bastante nuevo en los lenguajes de desarrollo web, pense que hacerlo asi de colocar primero el header antes que todo el resto de los tag, provocaria algun error de logica en el codigo ya que no seguiria un orden las instrucciones,por ejemplo hacer la validacion mediante sql sin siquiera haber declarado el boton de login(nose si me explico), de cualquier modo, probare lo que me comentaron y luego escribire la resolucion. Muchas Gracias! :D

Comment: Funciono perfectamente!, muchas gracias @Eric

Comment: @A.Cedano Funciono perfecto, mil gracias! , respecto al manual si he leido y ya al principio hacia referencia a lo que me comentaste, de todas formas al ser nuevo en php hay mucha terminologia que no manejo, asi que en algunas partes me cuesta comprender del todo lo que se esta planteando pero tratare de guiarme mas con el manual...

Comment: disculpen pero nose como marcar que la pregunta fue resuelta

Comment: Las cosas básicas consúltalas en el Manual, pero si tienes alguna duda puedes preguntar aquí, que para eso existe esta comunidad y alguien te ayudará con gusto. Si quieres escribe una buena respuesta poniendo cómo lo resolviste, qué fuentes usaste, etc, de modo que la respuesta pueda servir a otros. Luego marcas esa respuesta como aceptada aceptando la flecha de cotejo a la izquierda.

Comment: Pon esto en el inicio de tu código y va a funcionar `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`